# Closing the gap between my divs in normal flow

Tags: html, css

I'd like to figure out how to get control of gaps between my divs. I had set up the jello layout and started to work on my navigation bar, when gaps got all messy. Tried to backtrack everything and got left with just my divs in a default flow layout and gaps. Here is the html code:

```css
body { 
    background-image: url("images/ozadjeCrno.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    font-family:      Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:        small;
}

#container{
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header{
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.94);
}

#navigation{
    width: 900px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.94);
}

#navigation ul li{
    display: inline;
}

#logoLeft{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 60px;
}

#logoRight{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 60px;
    float: right;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.94);
    width: 255px;
    height: 100px;
}

#main {
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.94);
    height: 100px;
}

#footer{
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.94);
}


.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.roundedCorners{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Solska Impro Liga</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spletka.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <div id="header" class="shadow roundedCorners">
                <img id="logoRight" src="images/logo1.png" alt="logo1">
                <img id="logoLeft" src="images/logo2.png" alt="logo1">
            </div>
            <div id="navigation" class="shadow roundedCorners">
                <ul id="navButtonsList">
                <li><a href="" title="domov">DOMOV</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="domov">ŠILARJI</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="domov">O ŠILI</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="domov">ARHIV</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="domov">ENG</a></li>
                </ul>               
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar" class="shadow roundedCorners">
                <h1>SIDEBAR</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="main" class="shadow roundedCorners">
                <h1>MAIN</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="shadow roundedCorners">
                <h1>FOOTER</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wanted to post a screenshot, but I can't since I need 10 reputation points :/

Thank you for your time,
best regards.

Comment: But you can still include a jsFiddle... here, [I did one for you](http://jsfiddle.net/pze811vL/)

Comment: Try a CSS reset to remove the default margins, padding, border etc that browsers apply. Or for your example, `h1,ul{margin:0}`.

Comment: Thank you philtune for showing me jsFiddle, will use it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you have gaps between divs is because of heading tags. Use `overflow: hidden` for your parent divs than heading margin won't go out of box and than add margin to your parent divs so you can control distance between them.

If you don't want to use `overflow: hidden` than you can change heading tag margin to padding. Than again you can control distance between parent divs with margin.

Comment: You don't have shadow from right side at all? Can you show an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: I fixed it. It was my fault, I unknowingly also added overflow: hidden to #container.

Answer (score 0):

Certain child elements have a default margin, which is causing your issues:

`<ul id="navButtonsList">` is adding (for most browsers) `1em` or `100%` `margin-top` and `-bottom`. Same with all your `<h1>`'s.

You could do a "reset" at the top of your CSS, like:

```
ul, h1 { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Please don't add replies that were done before you. Overflow: hidden won't harm for box shadow, plus reseting heading tag margin to 0 will stick them to div border.

Comment: @D.Luss you're right about box-shadow... i think I was thinking of something else... still wouldn't recommend getting into the habit, though it would fix the OP's problem. Re: the margin:0 ... I posted that without seeing the comment.

Comment: @D.Luss also he said "reset", meaning you would later set the correct margin... of course...